# Running music in the background from google chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I am making a google chrome extension, where you press certain buttons, it starts, pauses, or restarts a song. I got it working but there is one problem. When I close the extension, the song stops! I need to know if there is a way around this. I have looked into background scripts and stuff, but I can't get them to work. Please help as this is one of my first google chrome extensions, and I would like to learn more. Thanks for any help you give me!

**Html:** (popup.html)

```
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
<script src="popup.js"></script>


</head>
<body>

<center>
<h1>Music Player</h1>
<h3>Songs:</h3>

<div id="ludicrous_speed">Ludicrous Speed 
<audio id="ludicrous" src="songs/ludicrous_speed.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>
<button class="Start" id="StartLudicrous">Start</button>
<button class="Pause" id="PauseLudicrous">Pause</button> 
<button class="Restart" id="RestartLudicrous">Restart</button>
</div>

</center>

</body>
</html>
```

**Javascript:** (popup.js)

```
function Start(song) {
song.play();
}

function Pause(song) {
song.pause();
}

function Restart(song) {
song.currentTime = 0;
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
var Start_Ludicrous = document.getElementById('StartLudicrous');
var Pause_Ludicrous = document.getElementById('PauseLudicrous');
var Restart_Ludicrous = document.getElementById('RestartLudicrous');

Start_Ludicrous.addEventListener('click', function() {
    Start(ludicrous);
});
Pause_Ludicrous.addEventListener('click', function() {
    Pause(ludicrous);
});
Restart_Ludicrous.addEventListener('click', function() {
    Restart(ludicrous);
});
});
```

**CSS:** (styles.css)

```
body {

width:300px;

}

.Start {
background-color: #42f46e;
border-color: #42f46e;
border-radius: 30%;
}

.Pause {
background-color: #f4e349;
border-color: #f4e349;
border-radius: 30%;
}

.Restart {
background-color: #e03838;
border-color: #e03838;
border-radius: 30%;
}
```

**Manifest:** (manifest.json)

```
{
"manifest_version":2,

"name":"Music Player",
"description":"Play Music",
"version":"1.0",

"browser_action":{
    "default_popup":"popup.html"
},

"permissions":[
    "activeTab"
]
}
```

Comment: Put audio play/pause in the background script/page and not in the popup.js

Comment: I tried. The background script can't access popup.html for some reason, so it can't play the audio.

Comment: Install "Noisly" chrome extension and research on it.

Comment: @elegant-user I can't find that extension

Comment: Its my bad I misspelled the name check out this: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/noisli/klejemegaoblahjdpcajmpcnjjmkmkkf?hl=en

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The document that `popup.html` creates exists *only as long as it's open.*

The moment the popup closes the `<audio>` element no longer exists.

A background page provides a solution to that - it exists independently of the popup.

You don't *normally* create a background page's HTML yourself, only provide a bunch of scripts. But nothing stops you from creating a DOM node on the fly:

```
// background.js
var audio_element = document.createElement("audio");
audio_element.src = "songs/ludicrous_speed.mp3";

audio_element.play();
```

Now, the popup's code won't be able to directly access the `audio_element` of the background page; you could do a quick hack job with `getBackgroundPage` methods, but it's preferable to learn how [Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) works and use `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` from the popup to control the background.

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to mark this as an answer earlier.